# Applications of the orbit stabiliser theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to teach the orbit-stabiliser theorem.

One nice application of the theorem is counting the number of symmetries of different platonic solids and regular n-gons (you count the orbit and stabiliser of some feature, e.g. a particular face).  Another is counting the number of distinct 'words' that you can get my permuting the letters of a given word, e.g. BANANAS (you want the orbit of the action of $S_n$ on the letters, which you find by dividing $n!$ by the size of the stabiliser.  In this case, the stabiliser has size $3!\cdot 2!$ - you can permute the As and the Ns separately.).

I'd like a couple of other examples of applications to demonstrate that the (finite) orbit-stabiliser theorem is useful.  Ideally, they would be of obvious interest outside of group theory and wouldn't require developing much theory to understand them.  (The two examples above meet both these criteria in my mind.)

Does anyone have any good examples?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Schreier generators (without the proof that they generate the subgroup) is quite easy and they provide natural solving moves for puzzles such as Rubik's cube, see e.g. page 98 in
[https://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/howtogap.pdf](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Ehulpke/CGT/howtogap.pdf)